# Why I need to use `at` with games

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

I would like to understand why do I need to use `at` with games?

For example,

He would be better at tennis if he practiced well.

Why I used `at` here and not `in` or `on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do **good**, **better**, **best**, **bad**, **worse**, and **worst** license a prepositional phrase headed by **at**?

The preposition **at** brings to the fore the sense of focusing one's energy and attentions, thereby casting its complement as something requiring such focus, an activity.

If a site manager asks a shift supervisor about a spill that needs to be cleaned up pronto, the supervisor might tell the manager:

> We're hard **at** it.

meaning, we are devoting our energies and attentions to that activity now.

Tennis is being cast as an activity by the preposition **at**.

Answer (score 1):

"Better" licenses a prepositional phrase headed by "at" as a complement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, I still do not understand why `at` fits better here than in or on.

Comment: @Maryam It's just that "better" requires a complement preceded by "at". There's nothing else to say. But you could say "It would be better in the house than in the classroom". In this case, "in the house" is an adjunct, not a complement.

Comment: @Maryam have you ever heard of someone being **good** at something? E.g. Frank is good at French. Better is the comparative

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you so much for your comment. I did not hear that before. But I am learning.